# Search functionality in 'taxonomy postbox' on edit post page

Tags: custom-taxonomy

- I created a custom taxonomy and added lots of terms.
- If I edit a page and want to add a certain term. It takes a lot of time to find the right one.

I would like to have the WP autosuggest search box.

How can I add the functionalitity that is already built on wp-admin/nav-menus.php?

[image: functionality that I would like to have on the edit page]

Hope anyone can help me to build this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`jquery-ui-autocomplete`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), which is [delivered with WP](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

The add an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) action that builds & filters the list.

You will have to deregister the `post_categories_meta_box` meta box and add your own, built on the core function [`post_categories_meta_box()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.4.2/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php#L304), as the core box hasn't got any actions or filters.